# JavaScript object properties undefined

Tags: javascript, object, geolocation

I'm trying to use geolocation to add current latitude and longitude to an object I can use later in an application, like so:

```
    var loc = {
    get_latlong: function() {
        var self = this,
            update_loc = function(position) {
                self.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                self.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            };

        win.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(update_loc);
    }
}
```

When I run `loc.get_latlong()` then `console.log(loc)` I can see the object, the method and the two properties in the console.

However when I try `console.log(loc.latitude)` or `console.log(loc.longitude)` it's undefined.

What is that all about?

Comment: That's all about you not knowing how _asynchronous_ methods are to be handled in JS - so please do some research on that topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others mentioned you can't expect result of an async call to come instantly, you need to use a callback. Something like this:

```
var loc = {
    get_latlong: function (callback) {
        var self = this,
            update_loc = function (position) {
                self.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
                self.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
                callback(self);
            }

        win.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(update_loc);
    }
}
```

then you call it using:

```
loc.get_latlong(function(loc) {
    console.log(loc.latitude);
    console.log(loc.longitude);
});
```